# Do you know of a C macro to compute Unix time and date?

Tags: c, static, unix-timestamp

I'm wondering if someone knows/has a C macro to compute a static Unix time from a hard coded date and time as in:

```
time_t t = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2012, 5, 10, 9, 26, 13);
```

I'm looking into that because I want to have a numeric static timestamp. This will be done hundred of times throughout the software, each time with a different date, and I want to make sure it is fast because it will run hundreds of times every second. Converting dates that many times would definitively slow down things (i.e. calling mktime() is slower than having a static number compiled in place, right?)

[made an update to try to render this paragraph clearer, Nov 23, 2012]

**Update**

I want to clarify the question with more information about the process being used. As my server receives requests, for each request, it starts a new process. That process is constantly updated with new plugins and quite often such updates require a database update. Those must be run only once. To know whether an update is necessary, I want to use a Unix date (which is better than using a counter because a counter is much more likely to break once in a while.)

The plugins will thus receive an update signal and have their on_update() function called. There I want to do something like this:

```
void some_plugin::on_update(time_t last_update)
{
  if(last_update < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2010, 3, 22, 20, 9, 26)) {
    ...run update...
  }
  if(last_update < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2012, 5, 10, 9, 26, 13)) {
    ...run update...
  }
  // as many test as required...
}
```

As you can see, if I have to compute the unix timestamp each time, this could represent thousands of calls per process and if you receive 100 hits a second x 1000 calls, you wasted 100,000 calls when you could have had the compiler compute those numbers once at compile time.

Putting the value in a static variable is of no interest because this code will run once per process run.

Note that the last_update variable changes depending on the website being hit (it comes from the database.)

**Code**

Okay, I got the code now:

```
// helper (Days in February)
#define _SNAP_UNIX_TIMESTAMP_FDAY(year) \
    (((year) % 400) == 0 ? 29LL : \
        (((year) % 100) == 0 ? 28LL : \
            (((year) % 4) == 0 ? 29LL : \
                28LL)))

// helper (Days in the year)
#define _SNAP_UNIX_TIMESTAMP_YDAY(year, month, day) \
    ( \
        /* January */    static_cast<qint64>(day) \
        /* February */ + ((month) >=  2 ? 31LL : 0LL) \
        /* March */    + ((month) >=  3 ? _SNAP_UNIX_TIMESTAMP_FDAY(year) : 0LL) \
        /* April */    + ((month) >=  4 ? 31LL : 0LL) \
        /* May */      + ((month) >=  5 ? 30LL : 0LL) \
        /* June */     + ((month) >=  6 ? 31LL : 0LL) \
        /* July */     + ((month) >=  7 ? 30LL : 0LL) \
        /* August */   + ((month) >=  8 ? 31LL : 0LL) \
        /* September */+ ((month) >=  9 ? 31LL : 0LL) \
        /* October */  + ((month) >= 10 ? 30LL : 0LL) \
        /* November */ + ((month) >= 11 ? 31LL : 0LL) \
        /* December */ + ((month) >= 12 ? 30LL : 0LL) \
    )

#define SNAP_UNIX_TIMESTAMP(year, month, day, hour, minute, second) \
    ( /* time */ static_cast<qint64>(second) \
                + static_cast<qint64>(minute) * 60LL \
                + static_cast<qint64>(hour) * 3600LL \
    + /* year day (month + day) */ (_SNAP_UNIX_TIMESTAMP_YDAY(year, month, day) - 1) * 86400LL \
    + /* year */ (static_cast<qint64>(year) - 1970LL) * 31536000LL \
                + ((static_cast<qint64>(year) - 1969LL) / 4LL) * 86400LL \
                - ((static_cast<qint64>(year) - 1901LL) / 100LL) * 86400LL \
                + ((static_cast<qint64>(year) - 1601LL) / 400LL) * 86400LL )
```

WARNING: Do not use these macros to dynamically compute a date. It is SLOWER than mktime(). This being said, if you have a hard coded date, then the compiler will compute the time_t value at compile time. Slower to compile, but faster to execute over and over again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula is in POSIX:

```
tm_sec + tm_min*60 + tm_hour*3600 + tm_yday*86400 +
    (tm_year-70)*31536000 + ((tm_year-69)/4)*86400 -
    ((tm_year-1)/100)*86400 + ((tm_year+299)/400)*86400
```

Source: XBD 4.15 Seconds Since the Epoch
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_15

Comment: R.. that is perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. I wrote date conversions before and was wary of the "complex" computations that the tm_year requires to determine Feb. # of days. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar

Comment: By the way, "yday" does take a bit of trouble to compute from month/mday since it requires knowing the number of days in February. But you should be able to derive that from the last 3 terms in the formula without much trouble. I'd factor your macro into a couple macros - first one to compute the # of days in feb for a given year, then a julian (yday) macro for a given year based on that, and finally plug those values into the above formula in a third macro.

Comment: The Algorithm to compute a leap year is well defined on Wikipedia. This at least works with the Gregorian calendar from before 1970.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm

Answer (score 2):

If you measured that it's *actually* too slow, then here is a practical simple workaround solution:

```
void myfun() {
  static time_t t = 0;
  if (t == 0)
    t = slow_unix_timestamp(2012, 5, 10, 9, 26, 13);
}
```

Now it's calculated only once.

Comment: -1, this is not C. `static` storage duration objects requires constant expressions as their initializers.

Comment: I will potentially have thousands of dates and I don't want to parse each one of them at compile time! Each one will be checked only once too. So there is no need for a static in my case. What I really want is a number at compile time.

Comment: sorry, what you wrote ("I want to make sure it is fast because it will run hundreds of times every second") suggested you recalculate these...

Answer (score 1):

Not a macro, but the timestamp will only be initialized once, subsequent calls to `get_timestamp()` will simple be a memory access.  You pay the initialization penalty at runtime, but only the first time `get_timestamp()` is called, knowing that you can initialize it early in your program and allow subsequent calls to be effectively "free".

```
time_t initialize_timestamp(int y, int m, int d, int h, int min, s)
{
   tm t;
   t.tm_year = y - 1900;
   t.tm_mon = m;
   t.tm.mday = d;
   t.tm_hour = h;
   t.tm_min = min;
   t.tm_sec = s;

   return mktime(&t);
}

time_t get_static_timestamp()
{
   static time_t ts = initialize_timestamp(2012, 5, 10, 9, 26, 13);
   return ts;
}
```

Comment: -1, this is not C. static storage duration objects requires constant expressions as their initializers.

Comment: When I answered, the question was tagged as `C++`.  That has recently changed :(.

Comment: OK, -1 removed. It's still not a good answer though; it just moves the overhead to run before main instead of after main starts, and leaves the data non-constant (and non-shareable) in memory.

Comment: I also thought I tagged my question as C++ since I'm writing C++. I guess Crazy Eddie changed that. I think C++ tag is more appropriate if C++ allows for such simplifications.

Anyway, I will potentially have thousands of dates and I don't want to parse each one of them at compile time!

Comment: Darn! I see I put the wrong negative in my comment here. "I DO want to compute them all at compile time" and not at run time, even if it "dramatically" slows down compile time.